# How to get R to label factors by level names using summary()?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm using summary for a linear regression, and usually the summary labels the coefficients with the names of the factor levels. However, when I use `options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))`,
 the summary comes out labeling the coefficients with variablename1, variablename2, instead of the names of the levels. How can I get it to display the level names instead?

If I have to do it manually, how do I know which coefficient is for which level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define the contrasts and, if desired, the labels manually for each factor, like this:

```r
data(iris)
contrasts(iris$Species)
#>            versicolor virginica
#> setosa              0         0
#> versicolor          1         0
#> virginica           0         1
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>       (Intercept)  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
#>             5.006              0.930              1.582
contrasts(iris$Species) <- contr.sum(3)
colnames(contrasts(iris$Species)) <- c("_setosa", "_versicolor")
contrasts(iris$Species)
#>            _setosa _versicolor
#> setosa           1           0
#> versicolor       0           1
#> virginica       -1          -1
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>        (Intercept)      Species_setosa  Species_versicolor  
#>            5.84333            -0.83733             0.09267
```